# How to redirect the user from register activity to main activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to redirect the user to "LoginActivity" when he clicks the button "CreateAccount" but it is not doing it, need help!
when I click the "CreateAccount" button once nothing happens but for the second time the Toast shows there is already a user with the same emailadress and in my database the user was registered, Can't figure out any problem.

```
//register activity

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText FullName, UserName, EmailAdress, Password,ConfirmPassword;
    private DatabaseReference Mrootref;
    private FirebaseAuth Mauth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        FullName=findViewById(R.id.FullName);
        UserName=findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        EmailAdress=findViewById(R.id.EmailAddress);
        Password=findViewById(R.id.Password);
        ConfirmPassword=findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPassword);
        Button createAccount = findViewById(R.id.CreateAccount);
        TextView logtxt = findViewById(R.id.blogin);

//        Database Reference
        Mrootref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Mauth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        createAccount.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            String txtFullName=FullName.getText().toString();
            String txtUserName=UserName.getText().toString();
            String txtEmailAdress=EmailAdress.getText().toString();
            String txtPassword=Password.getText().toString();
            String txtConfirmPassword=ConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtFullName)||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtUserName)||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtEmailAdress)||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtPassword)||TextUtils.isEmpty(txtConfirmPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You have missed something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (txtPassword.length() <= 7) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The Password must have atleast 8 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(!txtPassword.equals(txtConfirmPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "The Password You Entered is not same check it again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                registerUser(txtFullName, txtUserName, txtEmailAdress, txtPassword);
            }
        });



        logtxt.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class)));

//        Removeable Lines
        TextView skip = findViewById(R.id.skip);
        skip.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent hmActivity = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(hmActivity);
        });
    }
    public void registerUser(final String FullName, final String UserName, final String EmailAdress, final String Password){
        Mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(EmailAdress, Password).addOnSuccessListener(authResult -> {
            HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<>();
            map.put("fullname", FullName);
            map.put("username", UserName);
            map.put("emailadress", EmailAdress);
            map.put("id", Objects.requireNonNull(Mauth.getCurrentUser()).getUid());

            Mrootref.child("Users").child(Mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "User registration completed");
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Welcome to DreamOway!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Starting MainActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error in database operation: " + e.getMessage());
        });
    }
}
```

```
app level gradle build
```

```
`plugins {
     id 'com.android.application' id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.dreamoway' compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dreamoway"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}`
```

`//project level gradle.build`

```
`buildscript { dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

}
} plugins { id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false }`
```

Comment: I cannot spot the issue at a first glance, but since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Comment: You added this library ? `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-beta01'`

Answer (score 0):

The `createAccount` view isn't starting the activity because you defined the `logtxt` view to start the activity.  You would need to move the `startActivity` call into your listener on `createAccount` for it to work as you're describing.

Comment: it is still not working

Comment: sir still not working